# How do I generate PDFs from images in Objective-C? (on Mac OS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf-generation

I'm trying to build the code that will generate a single PDF from a bunch of images in Objective-C. Most of examples I've seen so far don't really allow me to build the PDF, but only generating Cocoa views and turning them into PDFs.

What I'm looking for is some toolkit (like Java's iText) that would allow me to generate a PDF from a bunch of images (with each image being a page in the PDF document).

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler with PDFKit.

```
PDFDocument *pdf = [[PDFDocument alloc] init];
for (NSString *fileName in fileNames)
{
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName]; 
    PDFPage *page = [[PDFPage alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [pdf insertPage:page atIndex: [pdf pageCount]];
    [image release];
    [page release];
}

[pdf writeToFile: @"output.pdf"];
```

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Mauricio Linhares Can you please explain what is PDF Kit and what other things are required to use the above code.I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: PDFKit is a framework for handling PDF files in Objective-C  - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/PDFKit_Ref/_index.html

Comment: any way to do this in iOS?

Comment: I am using same code to create PDF document on Mac os X 10.12. PDF is getting created but image is absent. What could be reason for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

See [Creating a PDF File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-CJBHHJCB) section in Quartz 2D programming guide.

There's a sample code to create a pdf document. All you'll need to do there is implement your custom `myDrawContent` function, where you can draw your images to pdf context same way as to any other CGContextRef.